# invalid typecast when Ninth enumeration added

Tags: delphi, ordinal

I have inherited some code that I need to modify.  The original is essentially what is below.  I need to add a ninth item to the enumeration list but when I do, I get an invalid typecast at "ord(byte(ts))";

```
program OrdTest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TFlag = (tsOne, tsTwo, tsThree, tsFour, tsFive, tsSix, tsSeven, tsEight); // , tsNine
  TStatus = set of TFlag;

function GetStatus(i: integer): TStatus;
var
  ts: TStatus;
  j: smallint;
begin
  try
    ts := GetStatus(4);  // returned from a table

    j := ord(byte(ts)); // Invalid typecast
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.Message)
  end;

end;

end.
```

since a byte can be any valid to 255, I don't  understand the exception.

What can I do so that I can add a ninth enumeration and still have the code function?

Comment: Not sure why that won't work for you, but I'm a bit more concerned about your recursive call to `GetStatus`... Does it not give you a Stack Overflow error?Also, where's the code that calls `GetStatus` in the first place? i.e. `begin` before `end.`

Comment: Do you mean **exception** or **compiler error**?

Comment: @JerryDodge: The code doesn't compile if you include `tsNine` in the enumeration. AFAICT this is what the OP talks about.

Comment: @Uli Indeed, but there are still several other issues in the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before you added `tsNine` you had 8 enum values, so a set of them took 8 bits and fitted into a `Byte`. Now you have 9 bits and need a `Word` to fit the set in. Therefore you'll have to cast to `Word` now. You can check `SizeOf(ts)` to see this for yourself.

Comment: I don't see this being a problem. I can't recreate the bug, even when fixing the code. I only get a Stack Overflow. OP's question is a mess... `GetStatus` is recursive, and the `i` parameter is never even used.

Comment: It fits the question title and quoted error message. But the question could be clearer.

Comment: @Jerry For sure this is a problem. You can't cast a two byte variable to a one byte type.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing 2 things.

#### Enumeration

Those are implemented as an integer value. By default, they are sequencial.  But you can also set specific values to them. For example :

```
type
  TEnum = (eOne, eTwo, eThree);
  TBigEnum = (beOne = 1, beTen = 10, beHundred = 100, beThousand = 1000);
```

Here, a TEnum would indeed fit in a single byte, up to value 255.  A TBigEnum would need a Word (because of value beThousand).

#### Sets

Those are implemented as an array of bits. "Enumeration 1" is the first bit, "enumeration 2" is the second bit, etc. if you have 8 enums or less, it will fit into 1 byte, 9 to 16, 2 bytes, etc.

Based on my previous example, 
    TEnum = set of enum
    TBigEnums = set of TBigEnum

would not compile, as the value "TBigEnum.eThousand" would be the 1001th(zero based) bit in the set, requiring a set of 126 bytes in size.  Delphi limits the size of sets to 32 bytes (maximum value = 255).